# <link rel= "preload" as="iframe"> Можно ли использовать для ускорения видео с Youtube?

Tags: javascript, оптимизация, iframe, видео

Подскажите, кто в теме, работает ли уже `<link rel= "preload" as="iframe">` ?
Задача состоит в необходимость ускорить предзагрузку видео с youtube которое запускается стандартной подстановкой `<iframe>` тега с его атрибутами, по нажатию на кнопку.
Согласно источникам [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content#What_types_of_content_can_be_preloaded) такой тип контента уже иметься, а вот согласно [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=preload) поддержка у него плохая (я именно про iframe type). Да и мой браузер говорит, что я как-то не правильно его предзагружаю. 
[image: Предзагрузка iframe]
Можно ли использовать preload - если я точно знаю, что данный контент будет нужен пользователю, по нажатию скажем на кнопку?

Comment: Как я понимаю на странице несколько фреймов и нужно ускорить загрузку страницы? Вы можете создавать обычные блоки, по айди загружать в них нужный постер с видео ютуба, а по клику на блок загружать уже сам фрейм, таким образом страница почти не нагружается

Comment: нет, меня интересует как раз предзагрузка. Когда ты нажимаешь на кнопку play а клип уже начал воспроизводиться, без задержки на дозагрузку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как сделал это я:

Нам нужно получить заставку видео и сохранить у себя, делаю это я на PHP. Т.к. вставляем только видео вида https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXX где XXXXXXXX это код видео, то можно распарсить ($url - ссылка):

```
$arr = explode('?v=', $url);
if(stristr($arr[1], '&')){
 $arr[1] = stristr($arr[1], '&', true);
}
$imageName = $arr[1];
```

Далее нужно настроить проверку из кеша или же в бд фиксировать картинки для каких кодов мы сохранили. Я делал на YII2, поэтому проверка кеша выглядит так

```
$code = Yii::$app->cache->get('image_yt_cache'.$imageName);
```

Если нашли в кеше, то ищем картинку в хранилище

```
if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/yt_images/'.$imageName.'.jpg')){
  $url_image = '/uploads/yt_images/'.$imageName.'.jpg';
}
```

Если в кеше нет или картинки нет - то скачиваем картинку, кешируем и сохраняем в хранилище:

```
//Типы разрешений ютуба
$types = ['maxresdefault','sddefault','hqdefault','mqdefault','default'];

foreach ($types as $type){
    $iteration = 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$imageName.'/'.$type.'.jpg';
    //Проверяем заголовки (существование файла)
    $headers = @get_headers($iteration);
    if(strpos($headers[0], '200')){
        if(!empty($iteration)){
            //Если звёзды сошлись - качаем изображение
            $curr_image = file_get_contents($iteration);
        }
        //Выходим из цикла, нам нужно макс доступное разрешение
        break;
    }else{
        continue;
    }
}
```

Дальше сохраняем картинку

```
$image_url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/yt_images/'.$imageName.'.jpg';
$url_base = '/uploads/yt_images/'.$imageName.'.jpg';
file_put_contents($image_url, $curr_image);
```

Ну и кешируем или записываем в БД что мы этот код уже получали с ютуба. У меня в YII2 это выглядит так:

```
Yii::$app->cache->set('image_yt_cache'.$imageName, $url_base, 10000);
```

Полностью функция выглядит таким образом:

```
function getImageYoutubeByUrlVideo($url){
    if($url){
        //Парсим URL ютуба, выделяем код видео
        $image = explode('?v=', $url);
        if(stristr($image[1], '&')){
            $image[1] = stristr($image[1], '&', true);
        }
        $imageName = $image[1];

        //Проверяем КЕШ
        $url_base = Yii::$app->cache->get('image_yt_cache'.$imageName);

        //Если нет кеша - гого
        if(!$url_base){
            //Проверяем, есть ли уже в папке изображение?
            if(file_exists(Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/uploads/yt_images/'.$imageName.'.jpg')){
                $url_base = '/uploads/yt_images/'.$imageName.'.jpg';
            }else{
                //Если картинки нет - сохраняем к нам в папку
                //Типы разрешений ютуба
                $types = ['maxresdefault','sddefault','hqdefault','mqdefault','default'];
                foreach ($types as $type){
                    $iteration = 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$imageName.'/'.$type.'.jpg';
                    //Проверяем заголовки (существование файла)
                    $headers = @get_headers($iteration);
                    if(strpos($headers[0], '200')){
                        if(!empty($iteration)){
                            //Если звёзды сошлись - качаем изображение
                            $curr_image = file_get_contents($iteration);
                        }
                        //Выходим из цикла, нам нужно макс доступное разрешение
                        break;
                    }else{
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                //Сохранение
                $image_url = Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/uploads/yt_images/'.$imageName.'.jpg';
                $url_base = '/uploads/yt_images/'.$imageName.'.jpg';
                file_put_contents($image_url, $curr_image);
            }
            //Прикешируем путь к картинке, чтобы каждый раз не грузить PHP
            Yii::$app->cache->set('image_yt_cache'.$imageName, $url_base, 10000);
        }
        return $url_base;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

А теперь дело за малым мы создаём ссылки с картинкой внутри и в src выводим нашу закачанную ранее картинку (опять же PHP):

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXX" class="video-play">
    <img class="image_youtube" src="/uploads/yt_images/<?=getImageYoutubeByUrlVideo("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXX")?>.jpg">
</a>
```

И на jquery поставил обработчик клика и добавил функцию разбора url на параметры:

```
function getUrlVars(href) {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function (m, key, value) {
        vars[key] = value
    });
    return vars
}

$(".video-play").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var videoId = getUrlVars($(this).attr("href")).v;

    $(this).parent().html('<iframe width="' + $(this).find('.image_youtube').outerWidth() + '" height="' + $(this).find('.image_youtube').outerHeight() + '" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoId + '?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
});
```

Таким образом, все видео вставляются красиво (можно добавить кнопку play по центру) и у нас не грузится куча данных со сторонних сайтов при загрузке. file_get_content очень грузит сайт, поэтому лучше кешировать и сохранять картинки загруженные с ютуба на долго. И если очень много видео на сайте будет и они будут каждый день добавляться - тогда лучше скачивать картинки с ютуба в админке при добавлении или же по cron.

Comment: Вы походу не поняли вопрос. Мне не картинки кешировать, мне видео бы мгновенно отдавать пользователю, без Ютубовских прогрузок (Ну или хотя бы постараться ускорить этот процесс). Как отдавать картинки, в Интернете очень много советов, от ленивой загрузки до 1рх изображения которое подменяется на правдивое, если пользователь дойдет до нужного контента....

Answer (score 0):

В общем, как я понял автора этого запутанного вопроса, то он имел в виду, что хочет загрузить контент на веб-страницу.

В данном случае это видео из *Youtube*, которое можно встроить в свою страницу при помощи `<iframe>`. Могу предложить тебе вставить этот тег и спрятать его при помощи *CSS*. Лучше при помощи `opacity` и `position:absolute`, а потом просто отобразить его, поменяв эти свойства при помощи *JavaScript*.